# Debugging PHPUnit tests in Homestead environment with PhpStorm

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, phpstorm, homestead

I have problems with running PHPUnit tests using `phpunit.xml` file. I configured remote PHP interpreter like this:

[image: Remote PHP interpreter configuration]

This configuration allows me to debug PHP Web Application. I have the problem trying to debug PHPUnit scripts. I configured it like this:

[image: PHPUnit configuration]

With such configuration I can debug PHPUnit tests:

[image: debugging PHPUnit test]

The problem is that my PHPUnit file is not read and my environment variables are not used. As a result I got some errors like CSRF Token Validation exceptions in my tests.

How do I use my `phpunit.xml` file? I can see I can add default configuration file in PHPUnit configuration. I need to specify there my project directory, not the `phpunit.xml itself`.

I can see in PHPUnit's `Command->handleArguments()` function there are only two ways to load this file. I can either specify the directory where `phpunit.xml` is located or don't use `--no-configuration` option.

[image: hendleArguments() function in Command class]

Unfortunately when I specify the directory where my project is located as location of `phpunit.xml`, I loose the ability to debug my tests. What's interesting, I can still debug PHPUnit scripts (for example Command.php file).

I'd like not to add `--no-configuration` option in IntelliJ (PhpStorm), but it is automatically added when the field "Default configuration file" is not selected.

How do I load `phpunit.xml` file without loosing ability to debug my tests?

Comment: Did you try to set it as a default configuration file in File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Test Frameworks > your remote PHPUnit configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the tests were run in isolation. When we specify either `phpunit.xml` file or project directory in PHPUnit configuration, the file is taken into consideration. What causes "detaching" debugger is running tests in isolation. To "fix" the problem we have to set attribute `processIsolation` to `false`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
     backupStaticAttributes="false"
     bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
     colors="true"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
     processIsolation="false"
     stopOnFailure="false">
...
</phpunit>
```

Comment: Or configure PHP on that VM to have xdebug enabled. See as well a simlar question on that part: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45332246/367456